# fake monitor in a headless device

Tags: x11, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry running headless (no monitor nor TV) I have some programs that need X11 environment to start (but for nothing more) like for instance a midi sampler.

I tried forwarding the X11 via SSH and it works like a charm. But I want to run those scripts by themselves heedlessly.

Is it possible to fool the system and pretend that there is a screen available?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14370/simulate-screen-in-a-headless-machine It's good that you proactively migrated this yourself, since waiting for a moderator to do it would take an indeterminate (and potentially infinite...) amount of time, but *if you leave a question on two sites you should include a link to the other on both.*  This way people will not waste time giving you an answer in one place when you've already found one somewhere else.  Looking for a CLI midi sampler would probably be a better solution, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) server.

You can install it with `apt-get install xvfb`.

For an example see https://superuser.com/questions/524811/how-can-i-run-lightdm-on-xvfb-on-a-raspberrypi

Answer (score 2):

I use [Xvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/Xvnc.1.php) to run programs on my server from my crontab¹.

During final testing of the programs that I run from crontab, this allows me to connect using the VNC viewer and as 
soon as everything works without input, 
I know they will from the crontab as well.

¹ <sub>I am running a program driven web browser.</sub>